# Autocompletion when searching in UISearchBar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, autocomplete, uisearchbar

I use a search bar in my CoreData app to find cities, and it is showing every possible match within my table view, like Google does. Google is providing a new searching facility: auto-completion of words (like XCode does with code -- IntelliSense). Can I implement this type of searching in `UISearchBar`?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171972/autocompletion-on-uisearchbar). If you use **UITableView** and **SqLite** you can check this [link](http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=228) It helps me a lot !!! Good luck !!!

Comment: Here is the very good blog tutorial on Google Type searching in UISearchBar http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=85

Comment: I tried this but I want like once I typed A It will auto complete word if any of them is present .xCode suggest codes..understood??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this previous SO question helps [Autocomplete search example for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077404/autocomplete-search-example-for-iphone)